# Flutter send messages/data to local IP

Tags: android, ios, flutter, tcp, udp

Currently I'm using UDP to broadcast messages to all the connected clients on a WiFi network (offline). Which works  just fine.
But as UDP obviously is limited, it is not a solution for me.

What I require is to  be able to send large bytes of data such as text, images & files offline to any client that's connected to a WiFi network without a secondary server.

Please point me in the right direction. I've searched for TCP related  posts but nothing very related came up as I need something offline as well as independent without connecting to a back-end server.

Thank you!

Comment: Why is UDP unsuitable?  Is it because you are using broadcast or is it because you want a streams-based solution?  You will probably need to use something like Bonjour/mDNS for multi-cast based service discovery.  Once you have a peer address then you can establish a TCP connection.

Comment: Doesn't UDP have limited usage, can UDP support large byte transfers such as images & files?

Comment: Not in a single packet.  You need to split the transfer into multiple packets and since UDP isn't reliable and doesn't guarantee delivery order (although I wouldn't expect out of order packets to be a problem on a local network) you would need to overlay a protocol to manage this stuff. Tcp makes this easier but you need to solve the rendezvous problem

Comment: I'm exploring the multiple packets idea, will post how  it goes!